# How to random sample from python itertools product?

Tags: python, combinations, python-itertools

I have a cartesian product obtained from `itertools.product`.
The number of combinations is 353,736,000 or even bigger. I can't afford to convert this result to a list because of time constraints.

I want to obtain 10 random combinations from those millions to become the population of a genetic algorithm and I need it to be done in a matter of milliseconds.

Is it possible?

Comment: You can do a random cartesian product multiple times instead of doing the full cartesian product then picking from that.

Comment: Why not just randomly sample from each axis?

Comment: Exactly, randomly sample from each of the axis (vectors). I was misled by my initial implementation, which aims at obtaining the entire search space to obtain optimality. When the order of magnitude is 10**8, then problem has to be solved by a heuristic and getting the entire search space is of no use. Each Chrommosome will get each of its component values by sampling randomly from each of the vectors.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is not necessary to obtain the cartesian product; for each of the vectors it is only necessary to randomly choose a value. Since each vector is a list:

```
import random

numberList = [111,222,333,444,555]
print("random item from list is: ", random.choice(numberList))
```

this will return a random element for a list. The same principle can be applied to other vectors to build the chromosome.